# How to update part of a DataFrame object with the values in another DataFrame object in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tow DataFrame objects:

obj1:

```
header1    header2    header3     header4
1          A          someValue1  someValue5
2          B          someValue2  someValue6
3          C          someValue3  someValue7
4          D          someValue4  someValue8
```

obj2:

```
header1    header2    header3      header4
1          E          someValue9   someValue13
2          F          someValue10  someValue14
3          G          someValue11  someValue15
4          H          someValue10  someValue16
```

I'd like to update `obj1` that keep the values in columns `header1` and `header2`, and set columns `header3` and `header4` to the values in `obj2`.

For example:

```
header1    header2    header3      header4
1          A          someValue9   someValue13
2          B          someValue10  someValue14
3          C          someValue11  someValue15
4          D          someValue10  someValue16
```

What I've tried is:

```
for ID in obj2.header2:
    obj1[obj1.header1==ID].header3 = obj2[obj2.header1==ID].header3
    obj1[obj1.header1==ID].header4 = obj2[obj2.header1==ID].header4
```

However, this doesn't change anything in `obj1`, it is still the same as before above code.

Is there a nice way to achieve my goal?

Please note that the examples are abstract, the real `ID` (AKA `header1`) may not 1-to-1 matched in `obj1` and `obj2`. So some IDs don't need to be updated. For example, `obj1` has ID 1,2,3,4,5, and `obj2` has ID 2,3,4,5. So ID 1 in `obj1` doesn't not have to be updated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
print obj1
   ID header2      header3      header4
0   1       A   someValue1   someValue5
1   2       B   someValue2   someValue6
2   3       C   someValue3   someValue7
3   4       D   someValue4   someValue8
4   5      D1  someValue41  someValue81

print obj2
   ID header2      header3      header4
0   2       E   someValue9  someValue13
1   3       F  someValue10  someValue14
2   4       G  someValue11  someValue15
3   5       H  someValue10  someValue16



df = pd.merge(obj1, obj2, on=['ID'], suffixes=['_l', ''], how='left').combine_first(obj1)
print df
   ID header2 header2_l      header3    header3_l      header4    header4_l
0   1       A         A   someValue1   someValue1   someValue5   someValue5
1   2       E         B   someValue9   someValue2  someValue13   someValue6
2   3       F         C  someValue10   someValue3  someValue14   someValue7
3   4       G         D  someValue11   someValue4  someValue15   someValue8
4   5       H        D1  someValue10  someValue41  someValue16  someValue81

df = df[['ID','header2','header3','header4']]
print df
   ID header2      header3      header4
0   1       A   someValue1   someValue5
1   2       E   someValue9  someValue13
2   3       F  someValue10  someValue14
3   4       G  someValue11  someValue15
4   5       H  someValue10  someValue16
```

Solution with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
mask = obj1.ID.isin(obj2.ID.tolist())
print mask
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: ID, dtype: bool

obj1.loc[mask, obj1.columns] = obj2.values
print obj1
   ID header2      header3      header4
0   1       A   someValue1   someValue5
1   2       E   someValue9  someValue13
2   3       F  someValue10  someValue14
3   4       G  someValue11  someValue15
4   5       H  someValue10  someValue16
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. However, in my case, some IDs don't need to be updated. Is there a  neat way to do it? Many thanks.

Comment: I think I dont understand. Do you mean some values are same, so update is not necessary?

Comment: Sort of like that, for example, I have ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in `obj1`, and in `obj2` the IDs are 2, 3, 4, 5. In this case, only 2, 3, 4, 5 in `obj1` have corresponding records in `obj2` to use. Therefore, only ID 2, 3, 4, 5 get updated in `obj1`.

Comment: Can you add it to your question and desired output? `ID` is `index`? This info is missing in question.

Comment: Hi jezrael. Thanks. I've updated my question. In fact, `ID` is not index, but `header1`.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous description.